# How does the symmetric decryption algorithm know the IV?

Tags: cryptography, aes

In [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=netframework-4.6), the IV is known to both the Encrypt and Decrypt methods because they're in the same scope of the `using(Aes myAes = AesCreate())`  block.  But when that is not the case, and it's never ever the same IV twice, how does the decryption routine get the IV?

Comment: Your supposed to send the IV along with the cipher text. Usually it is prepended. The IV is not a secret.

Comment: There are other ways of establishing an IV, for instance you could use a message sequence number, but note that for CBC (the default in .NET) the IV must be unpredictable (to an adversary, not to the sender / receiver of course). Including a fully random IV, mostly by prefixing, is certainly the most common method to make the IV unpredictable.